# Toggle a google chrome extension multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I have a my google chrome extension, when clicked it attaches event listeners to all elements on the page and inserts CSS (lol.js and style.css).

When I click the icon again, the icon changes, but I also want the JS and CSS to be removed. I can't seem to remove them. So right now I'm just trying to detach the event listeners

Then of course, I want when you click the extension icon again, add all that JS and CSS back. Is this possible?

This is how I have it set up now:

**background.js**

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
toggle = !toggle;
if(toggle){
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "lol.js" }, function() {
    })
  });
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
        file: "style.css"
  });
} else {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "undo.js" }, function() {
    })
  });
}
});
```

**lol.js** (the main js)

```js
var $body = $('body');

$body.append('<div class="the_result_one"></div>');
$body.addClass('steves_sweet_ext');

var clearIt = false;

function myClick(e) {
  $('.active_result_class').removeClass('active_result_class');
  if (clearIt) {
    $('.the_result_one').html('');
    $('.the_active_class').removeClass('the_active_class');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('hover-it')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('hover-it');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('hover-it');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
  var target_elem = $(e.target);
  target_elem.addClass('the_active_class');
  if ($('.the_active_class').length == 2) {
    var first_one = $('.the_active_class:first');
    var second_one = $('.the_active_class:last');
    $('.the_result_one').addClass('active_result_class');
    $('.the_result_one').html(calcPos(first_one, second_one));
    $('.the_active_class').removeClass('the_active_class');
    clearIt = true;
  } else {
    clearIt = false;
  }
}

function myMouseover(e) {
  var target_elem = $(e.target);
  target_elem.addClass('hover-it');
}

function myMouseout(e) {
  var target_elem = $(e.target);
  target_elem.removeClass('hover-it');
}

$('.steves_sweet_ext').on('click', '*', myClick);

$('.steves_sweet_ext').on('mouseover', '*', myMouseover);

$('.steves_sweet_ext').on('mouseout', '*', myMouseout);
```

**undo.js** (attempting to undo lol.js event listeners)

```js
$('.steves_sweet_ext').off('click', '*', myClick);
$('.steves_sweet_ext').off('mouseover', '*', myMouseover);
$('.steves_sweet_ext').off('mouseout', '*', myMouseout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions added in `lol.js` exist in that script's own sandbox and aren't visible in `undo.js` so you can't unregister them.

Use message passing to toggle the stuff right in `lol.js`:

- lol.js, add the listener:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
      if ("toggle" in message) {
          var target = $('.steves_sweet_ext');
          var onOff = message.toggle ? "on" : "off";
          target[onOff]('click', '*', myClick);
          target[onOff]('mouseover', '*', myMouseover);
          target[onOff]('mouseout', '*', myMouseout);
      }
  });
  ```
- background.js

  ```
  var toggle = {}; // each tab has its own state
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      var state = !toggle[tab.id];

      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: state ? "on.png" : "off.png", tabId:tab.id});

      if (tab.id in toggle) {
          // {frameId: 0} will throw on Chrome prior to v41
          try { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {toggle: state}, {frameId: 0}) }
          catch(e) { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {toggle: state}) }
      } else {
          // tabId param is optional, thus omitted
          chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "style.css"});
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "lol.js" }, function() {
              });
          });
      }
      toggle[tab.id] = state;
  });
  ```

As for CSS, the stylesheet is injected internally, not in `document.styleSheets` so there's no way to "toggle" it, but there are workarounds:

1. Prepend all selectors in `style.css` with some custom class: `body.someclass .selector` and in the `lol.js` simply toggle the body class (make sure the name is unique):

   ```
   document.body.classList.toggle("someclass", message.toggle)
   ```
2. Load the `style.css` contents and put it into an `<style id="someid">` element which you can toggle (make sure the id is unique):

   ```
   document.getElementById("someid").disabled = !message.toggle;
   ```